# Ionic 3 change variable/theme in build time

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, sass

I need to create 2 themes in ionic 3.
Actually I just need to have 2 versions of variables.scss file.

One will have one pallets of color, another one the same variables but different colors.

Is it possible to say ionic in build time which theme (variables.scss) to use, or somehow to change color pallet in build time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem with ionic build hooks.

Reference:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#hooks

In folder '\src\theme' I created one folder for every theme I have. Folder contains only variable.scss file with the color palette I need.

In ionic.config.json I added hooks according to documentation:

```
"hooks": {
    "serve:before": "./scripts/serve-build-before.js",
    "build:before": "./scripts/serve-build-before.js"
 }
```

I created folder scripts and added serve-build-before.js file which will be called every time build process start:

```
module.exports = function(context) {
    const fs = require('fs');

    if (context && context.argv) {
        let theme;
        for (let i = 0; i < context.argv.length; i++) {
            let argument = context.argv[i]; 
            if (argument.indexOf('theme.') > -1) {
                theme = argument;
                break
            }   
        }

        theme = (theme) ? theme: 'theme.defaultTheme'; // default theme

        const themeName = theme.split('.')[1];
        fs.copyFileSync('src/theme/' + themeName + '/variables.scss', 'src/theme/variables.scss');
    }

};
```

This code takes theme name from build argument, theme name is the same as folder name and this just copy variable.scss file from theme folder to main ionic theme folder.

Custom build process argument (in this case theme) should be send like this:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- --theme.themeName
```

Comment: Also work with Ionic 5.410, Ionic Angular 4.11.1. I was searching a way to customizing my theme without using environment.

An environment is dev, test, preprod, prod while the theme is the packaging for a particular client (a mobile app per client with its own theme).